# dplyr grouping help, how to select a value from another column based on vale of another, if empty replace with N/A

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with the following columns

userid:  unique value for an user

transactionId : unique value for the transaction  (an user can have many different orders)

created_at: date the order was created

webpage:  the web page were that user came to create that order (an user might have different pages for different orders or it can be empty)

I am grouping by user id with the code below to get some userid variables, but I need need one more variable after I group it, one called "firstpage"

that variable would be the first webpage that user has, so in other words the webpage value for that user id where the created_at has its minimum value, if there is no value for webpage on its minimum created_at value then use an "N/A" as its value for that userid

```
df_RFM <- data2 %>% group_by(user_id) %>% 
      summarise(recency = as.numeric(as.Date("2019-02-21")-max(created_at)),
                frequenci = n_distinct(transactionId), 
                monetary = sum(total_in_pennies)/n_distinct(transactionId), 
                last_active = max(created_at), 
                min(transactionId))
```

Any help in creating that "firstpage" variable please,  thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using `case_when()`. Have a go reading the documentation and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the created_at variable using 
`df_RFM <- data2 %>% group_by(user_id) %>%
arrange(.,created_at, .by_group = TRUE)` and then you could use `slice` to get the first row for each userID. Using that you could `mutate` a new column based on the webpage values.